# Why offsetWidth attribute is 0 in array of elements on DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a script that set some width to a few elements on the Dom, this few elements are getting with:
    `var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p.caption")`
the first 12 elements are good, with the right offsetWidth but the other half has the offsetWidth in 0.

I supposed that maybe because the Dom is no ready, or isn't loaded completely so maybe the elements are in a different state, with that attribute on 0, but I place the call to that function on the onload event in the Dom and is the same result, I look for the element inspecting the Dom and I can see it but the attribute still 0.

I also read about offsetWidth getting 0 but the only thing related to that says that maybe because the element in question has recently change on the Dom, and the offsetWidth is not updated, but in fact, i don not have any other function before this that pointed some Dom changes.

UPDATE:
Apparently I read a little bit more, and found that the offsetWidth is 0 when the element is on display:none; so there is a way to get the width of an element that is hidden.

Comment: If it could be that DOM is not ready, why don't you just wait for it to be?

Comment: Yup, I Add the function in a $(document).ready(function(){}); and is the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Per your 'Update':**

If you need to get the widths of elements you don't want displayed at the time of the function call, **don't** set their display to none and instead use something like this:

```
.noshow{
   position:absolute;
   top:-9999px;
   left:-9999px;
}
```

That will position them out of the view port, but keep them accessible to jQuery/javascript for measurement.